# Xamarin Forms and Engine.Razor. The problem with Microsoft.CSharp.dll access

Tags: c#, xamarin, razor

In my Xamarin Forms project, I am leveraging the Engine.Razor being successfully used in another WPF project as a lib. I use a call to existing function:

return Engine.Razor.RunCompile(htmlTemplate, "template_" + htmlTemplateFileName, null, templateDataModel);

It works for WPF but in my Xamarin Forms it throws:

"Could not find file "/Microsoft.CSharp.dll"

I experimented with adding/removing Microsoft.CSharp.dll version 2 and 4, I tried to add it to Xamarin Forms both as Assembly reference and as a Nuget package - no effect.

How to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like this library is outdated and targets .net framework only. There is no way to use it in Xamarin until it is ported to .net standard.

Comment: Well, even if I add Microsoft.CSharp 4.7 from Nuget, it is not working either with the same error message. The Microsoft CSharp 4.7 supports .NET Code and .Net Standard 2.0. Thoughts?

Comment: As I said there is **no way** to do that, this error is indirect result of more complicated build stuff, this library will give you nothing.

Comment: Ah, Ok. By your opinion, why it is working in WPF project which is .Net Core with the set of .Net Standard 2.1 libs?

Comment: This library? https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/

Comment: I think you mean RazorEngine.NetCore, it supports .net standard. Did you try clean rebuild after adding Microsoft.CSharp 4.7 nuget package? It seems to be right solution.

Comment: Sure thing I did. I been beat my brains out with it second day. Nothing helps. Only thing is when I forcibly copy Microsoft.CSharp.dll to "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myApp/files/.__override__/" folder when app starts, the error changes to something like "bool type is unknown". Looks like it is Ok now with finding dll itself but cannot recognize C# types. Thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228172/discussion-between-mabanza-and-alexey-rumyantsev).

Comment: @Mabanza From RazorEngine.NetCore dependencies, I am not sure whether can use RazorEngine.NetCore in xamarin.